# How to create and build a swift package

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I am trying to create a new swift package
i did the following commands on console

1. `swift package init`
2. `swift package generate-xcodeproj`

This works and generates an empty project.
Inside the project sample file i added just one line

`Import UIKit`

In Xcode, this builds correctly.
But on console, when I do `swift build` command,
I get this error

```
/Users/home/Desktop/TT/Sources/TT/TT.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'UIKit'
import UIKit
```

Is there any thing I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIKit` is a framework in iOS and won't be accessible.

```
#if canImport(UIKit)

// Code specific to platforms where UIKit is available

#endif
```

Related:

- [Creating a Swift Package with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/creating_a_swift_package_with_xcode)

Comment: your answer works. But I had to add this to all of my 50+ files. Is there some way to do this via some config?

Answer (score 2):

You should select an iOS based target to make it available:

[image: Demo]

<sub>If you leave it  selecting macOS (by default), you will get the error.</sub>

---

#### Specific platform

if you want your package to be available only for specific platforms (for example only for iOS), you should specify the platform in the `package.swift` file:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v9)
    ],
    products: [
,,,
```

---

#### Multiplatform

If you need your framework to be available on multiple platforms, don't forget to check the availability of the imported framework like:

```
#if canImport(UIKit)

import UIKit

// And do the rest of UIKit dependent code

#endif
```